# Business logic integrated into entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, business-logic

I've read some of the articles on BL, but the methodology seems counter intuitive to me.  It seems to break up normal OOP principles.  Here's an very simplified example: A client table contains the birthdate and gender of each client.  A life expectancy table contains the clientId, age, and probability of survivorship to that age.

Wouldn't basic OOP principles call for methods to be integrated into the entity?  E.g. the calculateSPTable() method in the client class.

```
class client {
  int clientId;
  int age;
  bool male;
  list<surviveProb> lifeExpectancy;
  void calculateLifeExpectancy(); // calculates lifeExpectancy
}
class surviveProb {
  int surviveProbId;
  int clientId;
  int age;
  double probability;
}
```

Yet the methodologies today seem to suggest such operations must be in a separate layer and a separate class.  Methods operating on entities should not be included in the entity framework entities.  This seems counter intuitive.  I really want to put methods into EF entities.  Is this going to lead to problems?  What am I missing here?

Comment: Entity Framework maps your entities object (ex. Properties, Methods, Enum etc.) thru Reflection. Now think about it, an entity have 10 properties and 10 methods compare it to another entity with 10 properties which will have faster mapping?

Comment: I think I understand property mapping, but I'm not sure how methods are mapped.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I now use some patterns that I think are good for maintenance porpoises and understanding the application.
Let's say you want to register an account.
In the controller, I would have an AddAccountViewModel that only exposes the minimum properties to a user. No worries about him injecting something bad in an unexpected property. Now, using dependency injection, I would call a Facade. Let's say _accountsFacade.RegisterAccount and I would pass the View Model as a parameter.
Inside this method in the facade, I would do the mapping from the View Model to the Model and this Facade would be responsible for doing everything that needed to be done so the account could be created. In my opinion, here is where all the business logic goes. In this Facade, using dependency injection again, I use a unit of Work and add and edit entities to the context. _unitOfWork.AccountRepository.Add(account)
You see? Controllers only "route" the application, facades handle business, unit of work handles the context, the repository only communicates with the data base... And the model only expose properties. 
This makes the mapping faster, as stated, and it separate concerns. Sometimes, the logic of adding an account may involve handling different objects that shouldn't be used inside the account object,

I hope you can understand what I want to explain, as my English is not so great.
Was it helpful?

Comment: It seems that the DBContext is the boundary that separates concerns, not the entities. DI occurs at the DBContext. The entities and business logic should not change with DI.  The key to the answer appears to be that mapping methods slows things down, but I don't understand what method mapping is how how it slows things down. It seems that methods should be ignored by mapping.